# Is there any alternate way to add and edit an outlook ToDo task without using GraphServiceClient in Xamarin forms application

Tags: xamarin.forms, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We are trying to update an outlook Task by using GraphServiceClient of Microsoft.Graph aPI (beta version) as -

```
 await AuthenticationHelper.GraphClient.Me.Todo.Lists[taskToDO.Id].Tasks[task.Id]
                      .Request()
                      .UpdateAsync(todoTask);
```

but when we update it we get this error -

> Status Code: BadRequest
> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: UnsupportedApiVersion
> Message: The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'https://outlook.office.com:444/todob2/graph/v1/users('...')/todoApp/lists('... ')/tasks' does not support the API version '1.0'.
> Inner error:
> Message: No route providing a controller name with API version '1.0' was found to match request URI 'https://outlook.office.com:444/todob2/graph/v1/users('...')/todoApp/lists('... ')/tasks'.

How to sole this issue ? Is there any alternate way to add and edit an outlook ToDo task without using GraphServiceClient ?

Comment: I've never used Microsoft.Graph, but see [Use Microsoft Graph SDKs with beta API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta?tabs=CS). The error message sounds like the code being called asks for "1.0 version" of an API, instead of asking for the "beta version" of an API. "Somehow" you need to make sure "beta" is used everywhere. Sorry, I don't know anything about what you need to look for or change. Can you use "1.0" SDK instead of "beta" - that would be easier to get working, I assume.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try to update the same task from Graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer. The API can be used for same is [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists/{list-id}/tasks/{task-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/tasks/%7Btask-id%7D)

In your request url, it seems that task-id is not present which is causing this issue.

Also, can you please also share the request-id being returned as part of failure response? We can debug this issue.

Comment: Please Use comments if you want to ask some questions, when you found a correct answer, then type it here.